# GFCI test failure

Tags: gfci, solar

I have a solar off grid small house with 8 circuits.  Two are 20 amp GFCI breakers installed in the panel.  Six have GFCI receptacles in the first outlet from the panel.  When a Sperry GFI6302 tester is installed into any receptacle the two amber lights appear indicating that the receptacle is wired correctly.  When the test button is pressed the tester the red light comes on, but the circuit does not trip on any of the circuits.  However, when I press the test button on the breakers or the receptacles the circuit trips.  What may be happening?  The GFCI receptacles were all installed this week.

Comment: Bad tester? Or one calibrated for a different leakage amount than the GFCIs? Or bad GFCIs...

Comment: Are your grounds to code? A push-button tester relies on a proper ground. Some off-grid houses are a bit more creative than code permits in their wiring schemes, though more recent ones tend to comply better, if anyone inspected it. But sometimes off-grid goes with somewhere that no inspector exists, or else nobody even bothered to inform the authorities that a house with electricity was being built...

Answer (score 2):

Unlikely that you have 2 bad GFCI/breaker and 6 bad GFCI/receptacle devices.

Which leaves two possibilities:

- Your tester is bad.

Unusual, but anything electronic can break, and that would fit with the problem happening "everywhere". Try a different tester - similar type, but maybe a different brand - e.g., [Klein RT210](https://amzn.to/48B9fxx).

- You have a ground problem.

If this happened on one circuit then I would suspect a neutral/ground problem in that particular circuit. Note that these testers do *not* have anything for "neutral/ground reverse" or "neutral/ground bonded" because it is *impossible* for a simple tester to figure out such things. But such things can lead to strange results.

For example, on the GFCI/breaker circuits or on any receptacle *after* a GFCI/receptacle, if neutral and ground are connected together then a GFCI test will likely not work as expected. That would not be the case with testing at a GFCI/receptacle, at least not in any way I can think of.

There could also be high resistance on the neutral-ground bond in the panel. You can test that with a multimeter from any receptacle. There could be a resistance value which:

- Would be low enough that enough current would flow to light up one of the lights on the tester so that it does *not* appear as "open ground"
- Would be high enough that not enough current would flow when the TEST button is pushed to trip the GFCI.

Update from comments:

> *when I run my old analog volt meter across the hot and neutral the voltage is close to 120 volts. When I test the hot to ground the voltage drops by about ten volts*

which means most likely one of two things:

- Ground (somewhere between where it is being tested and the main panel) has a really bad connection.
- There is no actual neutral-ground bond, so ground is not tied to neutral.

My bet is on the latter. **Check the main panel for a neutral-ground bond.** It is usually a single screw, but can also be a wire (or both).

Comment: Take the GFCI tester to some nice normally-powered house and check it there.

Comment: The system is grounded using a 8' grounding rod with, I believe, 4 bare copper wire.  The thing of note is that when I run my old analog volt meter across the hot and neutral the voltage is close to 120 volts.  When I test the hot to ground the voltage drops by about ten volts.  (I guess I need to invest in a better digital meter.)

Comment: A drop of 10V hot to ground vs. hot to neutral tells me **either your ground wire is messed up somewhere or you did NOT properly bond neutral and ground in the main panel.**